# Groovy ConfigSlurper gives Class file too large RuntimeException

Tags: java, groovy, runtimeexception

I am using the Groovy ConfigSlurper to load a large groovy file (741KB) from a Groovy script and consistently receive a RuntimeException when it tries to do the compilation.

Groovy 2.1.1, Java 1.6 (Apple/MacOSX)

I call it like so:

```
conf = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File('conf.groovy').toURL())
```

And always get the exception below. Is there a known limitation to the size of a file ConfigSlurper can compile?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Class file too large!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Class file too large!
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$15.call(CompilationUnit.java:797)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1036)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:573)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:551)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:528)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:244)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:202)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:212)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$parseClass.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse(ConfigSlurper.groovy:146)
  at groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$parse.call(Unknown Source)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
  at write_users.run(write_users.groovy:19)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.runScriptOrMainOrTestOrRunnable(GroovyShell.java:257)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:220)
  at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.run(GroovyShell.java:150)
  at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processOnce(GroovyMain.java:588)
  at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.run(GroovyMain.java:375)
  at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.process(GroovyMain.java:361)
  at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.processArgs(GroovyMain.java:120)
  at groovy.ui.GroovyMain.main(GroovyMain.java:100)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:106)
  at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:128)

1 error
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a known limitation but it is arguably not Groovy; it is the [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/) and ultimately Java.

As [Stuart Halloway](http://thinkrelevance.com/team/members/stuart-halloway) has mentioned in talks, it is often insightful to know what is happening one layer below your level of abstraction.

For example, [this link](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=/trunk/asm/src/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.java&rev=1622&peg=1622) shows that this code:

```
public byte[] toByteArray() {
        if (index > Short.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Class file too large!");
        }
```

... is likely the exception shown here:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Class file too large!
  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
```

Why does the ASM method throw this exception? [This post](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.ca/2010/01/reproducing-code-too-large-problem-in.html) states:

> It turns out that the magic number for the "code too large" error is
>   65535 bytes (compiled byte code, not source code).

It is probable that the file is too large for Groovy's internal implementation, which would result in a synthetic method that is too large for the JVM.